# Failed to create image decoder with message 'unimplemented'

Tags: java, android, bitmap

Cuento con el siguiente para tomar fotografia y mostrarla todo bien hasta que me tiene que mostrar la imagen en el imageview no la esta mostrando y en el logcat solo me muestra un error al querer realizar el decoder `Failed to create image decoder with message 'unimplemented'` les agradeceria si me pudieran decir que hice mal.

De lo que me percate es que al habilitar la linea de codigo `startActivityForResult(intent,1);` si me la muestra pero el problema al habilitarla es que al tomar la foto y presionar que la foto esta correcta me vuelve a abrir la camara vuelvo a tomar la foto y ahora si ya me la muestra en el imageview

```
private ActivityMainBinding binding;
    String rutaImagen;

    @SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        binding.btnCamara.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent;
                camaraLaucher.launch(intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE));
                if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null){

                    File imagenArchivo = null;

                    try{
                        imagenArchivo = crearImagen();
                    }catch (IOException ex){
                        Log.e("Error", ex.toString());
                    }

                    if(imagenArchivo != null){
                        Uri fotoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this,"com.example.myapplication.fileprovider", imagenArchivo);
                        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,fotoUri);
                        //startActivityForResult(intent,1);
                    }

                }
            }
        });
    }

    ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> camaraLaucher = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
            if(result.getResultCode() == RESULT_OK){
                //Bundle extras = result.getData().getExtras();
                Bitmap imgBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(rutaImagen);
                binding.imageView.setImageBitmap(imgBitmap);
            }
        }
    });

    private File crearImagen() throws IOException {
        String nombreImagen = "foto_";
        File directorio = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File imagen = File.createTempFile(nombreImagen, ".jpg", directorio);

        rutaImagen = imagen.getAbsolutePath();
        return imagen;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

El mensaje:

> Failed to create image decoder with message 'unimplemented'

Se produce en esta linea, en la cual tratas de decodificar la imagen usando  BitmapFactory.decodeFile() :

```
 Bitmap imgBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(rutaImagen);
```

La razon del error ocurre cuando no se puede decodificar la imagen, esto debido al formato de imagen el cual es incorrecto o simplemente no es una imagen.

El problema se encuentra aqui, el nombre de la imagen a obtener es "foto_.jpg",

```
  private File crearImagen() throws IOException {
        String nombreImagen = "foto_";
        File directorio = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File imagen = File.createTempFile(nombreImagen, ".jpg", directorio);

        rutaImagen = imagen.getAbsolutePath();
        return imagen;
    }
```

estas seguro que en verdad existe?